# How to combine multiple getServerSideProps function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have two pages; index.js and other.js, In the index.js I have a method `getServerSideProps`;

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) 
{
   //code here
}
```

I want to use this same function in the other.js page. Because the code in index.js getServerSideProps is pretty long, I had to import the `getServerSideProps` in index.js to other.js, doing something like;

```
import { getServerSideProps } from "./index";
...
export { getServerSideProps };
```

It works alright, but the problem is, I want to make another request in the `getServerSideProps` that only runs in the other.js page. One way of doing this is to copy the `getServerSideProps` code I wrote for the index.js and paste it in other.js and modify the code. The problem is, like I mentioned earlier, the code is quite huge in the `getServerSideProps` and I don't want to copy it and paste it in all the pages I need it.

My question is, how do I add another `getServerSideProps` to the one I already exported from another page. Basically, I want to merge the exported `getServerSideProps` in index.js to the `getServerSideProps` I have locally in other.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse the same `getServerSideProps` function, but conditionally run specific code based on which page it's being called from, you can try making use of the `context.req` object:

`index.js`

```
export default function Home({ data }) {
  return <>{data}</>;
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let foo;

  // Parse `message.url` into parts. An alternative to using the `URL` class
  // would be to use `context.resolvedUrl`, but that will take more effort to
  // isolate pathnames when query parameters are involved.
  const reqUrl = new URL(
    context.req.url,
    `https://${context.req.headers.host}`
  );
  const thisPage = reqUrl.pathname;
  const queryParams = reqUrl.searchParams;

  switch (thisPage) {
    case "/":
      // code for index.js
      foo = "Hello, index.js!";
      break;

    case "/other":
      // code for other.js
      foo = "Hello, other.js!";
      break;

    default:
      foo = "Hello, world!";
  }

  // common code
  console.log("`thisPage`:", thisPage);
  console.log("`context.resolvedUrl`:", context.resolvedUrl);
  console.log("`queryParams`:", queryParams);

  return {
    props: { data: foo },
  };
}
```

`other.js`

```
import { getServerSideProps } from "./index";

export default function Other({ data }) {
  return <>{data}</>;
}

export { getServerSideProps };
```